# Chrysler 300 shifts from Drive to Reverse when going uphill

Tags: automatic-transmission, shifting, chrysler-300

This is a 2012 Chrysler 300.

Had recall done labor day weekend on gear shift software and now when I go up a hill the car jumps from drive to reverse and rolls back.

Then later on 3 to 4 hours later the car starts jumping form drive to park, reverse to park, neutral to park. I have to let it sit for 30 minutes on level ground before I can move it into gear. Every time I go up a hill this happens.

I took it back to the dealership, they did another recall on it and it broke down again two weeks later with the same problem. Now they are saying I wasted something in gear shift that's what causing the problem. How can they do a recall on software if I messed it up? Please help.

Comment: As you drive up a hill, the car jumps from drive to reverse? What? How fast are you traveling when this happens?

Comment: There was a legitimate problem with the gear shift software on the 2012 Chrysler 300, the car would not warn the driver when they are trying to get out of the car and it's not in Park. This is what the recall is for, and has nothing to do with whether or not something is damaged in the shifter.

Answer (score 3):

Take it to another dealer and have them redo the software update and assess it following this. Mechanics are mechanics. In my experience, they are embarrassingly bad at working with software.

When they can't get it to work like turning a wrench they start throwing around accusations at the customer. Been there done that and, boy, does it irritate me. Last time I was told something like "apparently you've been tampering with the on-board computers".... Really?? Took it to another shop- updated, no issues.

Comment: I agree, a failed software update is likely.

Comment: updating software on engine/transmission/whatever computers are isn't the same as updating pc software. when flashing fails on a cars computer it'll brick and need to be bench flashed to be operable again. if an incorrect rom file was flashed that might explain the symptoms.

Comment: Not that I'm a pro, but I have flashed ECUs and other SoC style hardware. (If I was charging people money for it, I would hope I'm a pro) If the TCU was bricked, she'd never have gotten out of park, but you're right, [practically] irreparable damage could have been done to the TCU. The TCU could be flashed into an irrecoverable state.